# How to match two different multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have two array I want to match `['Name']` value of second array `[Seltemgr]` value, if   `['Name']=>value == [Seltemgr]=>value` then `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">` else unchecked, Is this possible to match two multidimensional array having different no of element with different keys.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tnid] => 45
        [Name] => Financial Tips      
        [Email] => Array
        [Href] => http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tnid] => 42
        [Name] => Products            
        [Email] => Array
        [Href] => http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tnid] => 44
        [Name] => Health Tips         
        [Email] => Array
        [Href] => http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [tnid] => 43
        [Name] => Personal Events     
        [Email] => Array
        [Href] => http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [tnid] => 41
        [Name] => Calendar            
        [Email] => Array
        [Href] => http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/1
    )

  )

  Array
  (
[0] => Array
    (
        [emarketid] => 77
        [agentid] => 81
        [customerid] => 16901
        [Seltemgr] => Calendar                                          
        [seltemname] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [emarketid] => 78
        [agentid] => 81
        [customerid] => 16901
        [Seltemgr] => Financial Tips                                    
        [seltemname] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [emarketid] => 79
        [agentid] => 81
        [customerid] => 16901
        [Seltemgr] => Merry Christmas                                   
        [seltemname] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [emarketid] => 80
        [agentid] => 81
        [customerid] => 16901
        [Seltemgr] => Drip financial tip 3                              
        [seltemname] => 
    )

  )
```

Comment: Can you match them? Yes. Just check which key isset and then check that value. But what do you want to do after matching? Because you didn't say.

Comment: might be use array_intersect() instead

Comment: Just found this answer from last year http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935689/php-how-to-match-two-multidimensional-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
$match = [];

foreach ($array1 as $k1=>$a1){
      foreach($array2 as $k2=>$a2){
                 if($a2['Seltemgr'] == $a1['Name']){
                         $match[] = array($k1,$k2);
                 }
       }
}
```

So $match contains the index of each array where the Name and Seltemgr match. Not saying this is the optimal way to do this but The intersect functions often require keys to match up.